# Can you improve a mysql update with two embedded selects with joins?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables used in this query:

1. instructor (contains a "soft" deleted column)
2. school (contains a "soft" deleted column)
3. instructor_school (association table between instructor and school)

If a school is marked as deleted, I want the instructors at that school to also be marked as deleted, but *only* if *all* of their schools are marked as deleted. Here's my proposed query:

```
update instructor as i
set deleted=1
where
(select count(*) from instructor_school as i_s join school s
 on s.id=i_s.school_id
 where i_s.instructor_id=i.id) = 
(select count(*) from instructor_school as i_s join school s
 on s.id=i_s.school_id
 where i_s.instructor_id=i.id and s.deleted=1);
```

If we only allowed each instructor to be in a single school, the query would be much simpler:

```
UPDATE instructor i
JOIN instructor_school as i_s ON i_s.instructor_id = i.id
JOIN school as s on s.id=i_s.school_id
SET i.deleted = 1
where s.deleted = 1
```

My question is - is this query the best approach to solve this problem - or can you suggest a better query?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE instructor AS i
JOIN instructor_school i_s_deleted ON i.id = i_s_deleted.instructor_id
JOIN school s_deleted ON i_s_deleted.school_id = s_deleted.id AND s_deleted.deleted = 1
LEFT JOIN instructor_school AS i_s_active 
    JOIN school s_active ON i_s_active.school_id = s_active.id AND s_active.deleted <> 1
ON i.id = i_s_active.instructor_id 
SET i.deleted=1
WHERE i_s_active.school_id IS NULL;
```

What I did here was first I joined to instructor_school to and to school to make sure that there is a school that is deleted. Then I left joined to instructor_school and school again as active and then I put where i_s_active.school_id is null into my where clause. This will ensure that the instructor is not associated to any active schools.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much! This is much cleaner and presumably more efficient. I'll use it instead of my proposed query above.

Comment: Doesn't the on clause for the left join for instructor_school  have to be at the end of that line and before the join for s_active? Also, a) there should not be any rows in the association table with one column as null, and b) if the instructor is associated with a non-deleted school, then we don't want it to be marked as deleted. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: 1) I was using a JOIN within the LEFT JOIN - because I want to LEFT JOIN to instructor_schools in so that I will not exclude any instructors, but I want to do an INNER JOIN to school because I want to return ONLY the schools that will return from my LEFT JOIN to instructor_schools. If you want to switch this, you would have to change the JOIN to school (s_active) to a LEFT JOIN as well.
2) a)I am not understanding this question.
   b) That is exactly what we are doing by putting in a LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN to active schools WHERE i_s.active IS NULL.

Comment: To explain in English, the JOIN to active schools within the LEFT JOIN to instructor_schools is saying "find any active school that this user is associated to, if that exists, exclude him from the update. I hope this helps to clarify!